# How to do nested JSON objects in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, json

I've made two tables for demonstrational purposes;

```
CREATE TABLE 'owners' (
    'id' int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    'firstname' varchar(20) NOT NULL, 
    'lastname' varchar(20) NOT NULL
);
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE 'cars' (
    'id' int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    'owner_id' int NOT NULL, 
    'brand' varchar(20), 
    'model' varchar(20)
);
```

I want to achieve this JSON:

```
[
   {
      "brand":"volvo",
      "model":"xc90",
      "owner":{
         "id":"1",
         "firstname":"Jon",
         "lastname":"Doe"
      }
   },
   {
      "brand":"bmw",
      "model":"m5",
      "owner":{
         "id":"1",
         "firstname":"Jon",
         "lastname":"Doe"
      }
   },
]
```

What should my query look like?

I've tried:

- JSON_ARRAYAGG()
- JSON_OBJECT()
- JSON_EXTRACT()
- Look at the documentation
- Looking for solution all over the internet
- Read almost every related Stackoverflow question and answers

Comment: Join the tables and use `JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT(...))`.

Comment: @Barmar done, i didn't expect anyone to give me the whole solution, but it looks like I can't complete it by myself, because I have never done anything like this before. Thanks :)

Comment: "I have tried..."   But why doe you not share the SQL that you tried ?

Comment: Why would you use `JSON_EXTRACT`? You have no JSON in the tables to extract from.

Comment: I've tried to follow many documentation, and one of them wrote to use JSON_EXTRACT, i wasn't sure if I really have to use it, but I've tried it as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Join the two tables to relate the cars with their owners.

Use `JSON_OBJECT()` to create the JSON objects, and combine them all into an array with `JSON_ARRAYAGG()`.

For the nested object, simply use a nested call to `JSON_OBJECT()`.

```
SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(
    JSON_OBJECT('brand', c.brand, 'model', c.model,
        'owner', JSON_OBJECT('id', o.id, 'firstname', o.firstname, 'lastname', o.lastname)
    )
)
FROM cars AS c 
JOIN owners AS o ON o.id = c.owner_id
```